# Google generated BigQuery file is corrupted all the time

Tags: google-bigquery

> ```
> select * from   gpqueries:contracts.raw where    fiscal_year =2015
> ```

ignore case

Whe generating data as JSON or CSV from google big query, and getting data as below when downloaded it from storage bucket.

Please guide me why this happens. Also how can combine multiple files, if generated files are multiple.

[image]

***Update :***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot I can see that the first 3 characters are 1F8B08 - that's the signature of a gzip compressed file. Just uncompress it with gunzip.

http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=1F8B08&mode=SIG

My guess: Did you pick "compression: gzip" when exporting?

Comment: if you see the screenshot above. The file which downloaded is in json extention. How can i extract that file?

Comment: what you said is true, its a zip file. I extracted it. Thanks for guiding.

Comment: but if i download in csv format, it getting junk characters. This i faced on 1st of Aug. So tried creating dataset in json format. It given data properly. Please can you check on this. I need this data in csv file, it is difficult to combine all this json files to csv if it is huge files

Comment: Please check the screenshot attached above.

Comment: isn't it the exact same problem? (gunzip first?)

Comment: no its not same problem, it shows characters in few editors like Sublime text, but not on excel or notepad. also unable to read the file using python or any language. Please guide me on this. If needed i can share the csv flie through google drive.

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: please share your mail id to share through goolge drive

Comment: office network blocking above site. I do when i reach home

Comment: or any alternative

Comment: make the file public on gdrive and share the url?

Comment: while creating either csv or json flie please append content type , this could solve the above problem i hope.

Comment: oh is it? ok, i need some more information like, at what size google bigquery zip the files?

Comment: show me a screenshot of the dialog you get when you try to export a table

Comment: Please check added screenshot

Comment: you are sure you didn't choose the 'gzip' option there?

Comment: (how did you move the files from GCS to your computer?)

Comment: I click on the file, it get downloaded. Iam cross checking again for ur previous question

Comment: I havnt checked gzip this is the url i sepecified by selected CSV in dropdown "datasetsample/newdataset/dataset2015_*" it generated CSV files with no extention, it havnt zipped now.

Comment: Please check the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120574/discussion-between-developer-and-felipe-hoffa).